# Mac OSX App Installation?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, installation

I'm testing an application I created in Xcode, archived and then 'shared' on the organizer - in order to test the installation process before submitting to the App Store. After I clicked the .pkg and installed it, it said it was successful, but the application doesn't show up in my Applications folder. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Do I need to attach a certificate with it before it will show up there?

Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely getting relocated for you by Installer. It's probably overwriting the copy of the app in your Build folder. If you want to verify this, you can open the Log window in Installer while testing the package. To prevent the redirection, you can delete the build result (maybe archive the .app and .dSYM for later debugging) and install again.

Comment: Sometimes Installer can be a bit TOO helpful.  It's great for most people, because it prevents them from getting multiple copies of an app installed.  It's just that devs have one more thing to worry about.

Comment: Christian, thanks for your help brotha. Yeah you weren't kidding that was a nightmare it must have installed in 5 different locations (I had to remove them by looking in Log) before installing correctly in the Applications folder). By default, it will install there yeah? Like from the app store?

Comment: Yes, for most people Installer will do the right thing - replace the oen copy they have with the new copy when upgrading.  When you removed all the existing copies, you prevented it from "upgrading" an installed copy and instead had it install a new copy.  Your users will see this functionality - so it will install to the Applications folder just like they want.